# How to implement 'Open on focus' and 'monthpicker' to Angularjs calendar?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am new to Angularjs, how can I add open on focus implementation  (similar as Microsoft Windows 7 calendar) to my calendar as given below where we using Angular material version1.0.1.  We decided not to update our Angular material to 1.1.1.

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="datepickerBasicUsage">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.0.1/angular-material.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div ng-controller="AppCtrl" style='padding: 40px;'>
    <md-content>
      <md-datepicker ng-model="birthdate" placeholder="Enter date" md-max-date="maxDate" ng-focus="open()"></md-datepicker>
    </md-content>
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.0.1/angular-material.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

**app.js---**

```
angular.module('datepickerBasicUsage', ['ngMaterial'])
  .controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.birthdate = new Date();

    $scope.maxDate = new Date(
      $scope.birthdate.getFullYear(),
      $scope.birthdate.getMonth(),
      $scope.birthdate.getDate());

    $scope.open = function() {
      $timeout(function() {
        $scope.birthdate = new Date();
        $scope.maxDate = new Date(
          $scope.birthdate.getFullYear(),
          $scope.birthdate.getMonth(),
          $scope.birthdate.getDate());
      }, 400);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a directive named the same as the existing datepicker directive. This way you won't have to add anything to the HTML, as you are already using `md-datepicker`.

```
app.directive('mdDatepicker', function() {

  return {
    link: function(scope, element) {

      var controller = element.controller('mdDatepicker');

      var event = {
        target: document.body
      };

      var input = element.find('input');

      input.on('focus', function(e) {

        scope.$apply(function() {
          controller.openCalendarPane(event);
        });
      });

      input.on('click', function(e) {

        e.stopPropagation();
      });
    }
  };
});
```

The directive retrieves the controller that the normal `mdDatepicker` directive uses and simply calls the `openCalendarPane` method when the input is focused.

The fake event object is needed since `mdDatepicker` uses `event.target` internally to know what to set focus to when the datepicker is closed.

The click listener and `event.stopPropagation` is needed for it to work in Firefox (at least in the version I tested with), or the calendar would just close instantly again if opened by clicking inside the input.

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/YdtVwa3MnTyrl5wS1eZ8?p=preview

Comment: thanks for trying it, Demo which you mentioned not working as expected. open on focus (by clicking on calendar)  has to work.

Comment: @user7303839 Works just fine for me. Which browser are you testing on?

Comment: we tried it in chrome 54.0.2840.100 and IE11 can you correct it and point the right solution for it?

Comment: @user7303839 No I can't. It works on two computers for me, both in Chrome 55 and IE11.

Comment: @user7303839 If you remove my directive, can you open it by clicking the icon?

Comment: @user7303839 Just had two friends try it and it works for them as well in Chrome at least.

Comment: OK.. we are trying to implement md-open-on-focus(https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/datepicker) feature which is given in the angular material 1.1.1 (latest), with out updating our project angular material version 1.0.1. which gives calendar years&months by clicking on icon of the year.. which is not working for your demo given.Is there anything blocking by browser?

Comment: @user7303839 Clicking on the year icon inside the calendar does not exist in 1.0.1. In the question you wrote 'open on focus', which is something else, and what I implemented.

Comment: I mentioned "similar as Microsoft Windows 7 calendar" it is same as open on focus feature which is given in the angular material 1.1.1  (md-open-focus) directive dos.

Comment: @user7303839 The `md-open-on-focus` in 1.1.1 is for opening the calendar when the input field is focused, as I implemented.

Comment: How about your demo given, how it works? how can i implement the calendar when input field is focused to fulfill my requirement

Comment: @user7303839 If you open the demo I posted and click on the input field, does it not open?

Comment: Got it..great.. but my requirement is to open the calendar when we click on calendar icon (eg: Dec 2016) it is same as open on focus feature which is given in the angular material 1.1.1 (md-open-focus) directive

Comment: @user7303839 There is no `md-open-focus` directive, is there? There is `md-open-on-focus` which makes the calendar open when you focus the input.

Comment: Its typo.. I know we can achieve it by using version 1.1.1 <md-datepicker ng-model="myDate" md-placeholder="Enter date" md-open-on-focus=""></md-datepicker>

Comment: Please suggest to implement this feature in 1.0.1 version thanks

Comment: @user7303839 I'm not sure what you want. The thing I have implemented is what the `md-open-on-focus` in 1.1.1 is doing. It opens the calender when you focus the input.

Comment: 1.1.1 version calendar is clickable when we click on the (Dec 2016) it give months of year and soon.. but your demo doesn't?

Comment: That is correct, but that wasn't what you asked for in the question. You asked for "Open on focus", which means the calendar opens when you focus the input, like `md-open-on-focus`.

Comment: @user7303839 I'm sorry that I misunderstood what you were after. I will take a look at the other problem tomorrow.

Comment: added new question for it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41250474/how-to-extend-datepicker-directive-with-monthpicker-in-calendar-pane